# Access SQL-Query ORDER BY Alias-Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question about a simple sql-query.

This is my query in Access 2013:

```
SELECT Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName, SUM(Orders.TotalPrice) AS TotPr FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.Shipper_ID=Shippers.Shipper_ID
GROUP BY Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName
ORDER BY Shippers.ShipperName;
```

... and it work perfect. But how can I put the alias-column (TotPr) in ORDER BY?

Thank you for help :)

Comment: Did you try using either `ORDER BY Shippers.ShipperName, TotPr` or `ORDER BY Shippers.ShipperName, SUM(Orders.TotalPrice)`?

Comment: I tried this: ORDER BY TotPr; but it does not works.

Comment: And the other option?

Comment: Thank you Lamak! It works: ORDER BY SUM(Orders.TotalPrice);

Comment: you should've put it as an answer Lamak!

Answer (score 2):

Order By generally doesn't like calculated columns, due to the way SQL is figured internally by most engines.  Try this:

```
SELECT Shipper_ID, ShipperName, TotPr
FROM
(SELECT Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName, SUM(Orders.TotalPrice) AS TotPr FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.Shipper_ID=Shippers.Shipper_ID
GROUP BY Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName) ShipQuery
ORDER BY ShipQuery.ShipperName, ShipQuery.TotPr;
```

(Disclaimer: I didn't test this.)

Comment: This absolutely works; even better, if your query is based on a query you CAN use the first query's aliases in ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula:

```
SELECT Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName, SUM(Orders.TotalPrice) AS TotPr
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN
     Shippers
     ON Orders.Shipper_ID=Shippers.Shipper_ID
GROUP BY Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName
ORDER BY Shippers.ShipperName, SUM(Orders.TotalPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM(Orders.TotalPrice)` instead of the aliased name, you want the aggregation

so your query would be:

```
SELECT Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName, SUM(Orders.TotalPrice) AS TotPr
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN
     Shippers
     ON Orders.Shipper_ID=Shippers.Shipper_ID
GROUP BY Shippers.Shipper_ID, Shippers.ShipperName
ORDER BY Shippers.ShipperName, SUM(Orders.TotalPrice);
```